# Handling multiple states in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, state

Currently, I try to figure out the best way how to handle states in my Rails app.

I have a model (Draws) which handles multiple states in three dimensions.

- active / inactive
- started / running / ended
- not_full / full

There are five states I need to handle:

- inactive & all other states
- active & not_started & not_full
- active & running & not_full
- active & running & full
- active & ended & full

Can somebody point me into the right direction regarding gems to use or articles to read to learn more about how to deal with states in Rails?
Is it the correct way to combine the different attributes towards states?
Do I have to define every transition separately?

Comment: I think the best way to handle stats would be to use the state machine gem.
I have been wanting to apply this to my existing app for a while, but other things take priority first.
https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine
I Think it would benefit everybody that once you get this working, you return here and report. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually incorporate gems to handle state machines, as I usually have to fine tune access and transitions that usually go beyond the functionality of the gem.  Instead I just define everything about the state machine that I require in a hash and then create methods in the model to work with the definition.

```
   class Draw
      STATES = {
        inactive: {
          label: "Inactive",
          transition: ->(draw) {
            # code here that handles the transition to inactive state
          }
          from: [:started, :running, :ended],
          guard: ->(draw) {
            # code here that indicates that this state can be transitioned 
into
            !self.running? 
          }
        }
        started: {
          # as above
        }
      }

      STATES.keys.each do |s|
        define_method "#{s}?" do
          self.state == s.to_s
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: That looks like a good approach. What does
"guard: ->(draw)"
mean?
Haven't seen this in a hash before.

Comment: ->()  is just shorthand notation for lambdas.. Your views can all this method on all the states to see which state it can legally transition into.